# Rolling sums in SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I need to find out how many times an event has occurred in the past x-day, rolling interval interval. In a 2-day case, this can be accomplished without too much of a headache.

```
WITH lagged AS 
(SELECT 
   IF(attr IS NOT NULL, 1,0) AS is_curr
   IF(LAG(attr, 1) IS NOT NULL, 1,0) AS is_prev
FROM tab)
SELECT 
   SUM(is_curr, is_prev) AS occurences_in_x_days
FROM lagged
```

However, if I want to change x to something like 7, 30, or 90, this design comes impractical.
Is there a more scalable option?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

count(attr) over(date rows between x(Enter no of days here) preceding and current row) as rolling_sum